# MassTransit cant create project

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am trying to follow the start of the MassTransit setup. I have made sure I have installed .net core 5.0. https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/ and watching the Video youtube.com/watch?v=nYKq61-DFBQ but when I run the following command, it seems to run ok but not sure if anything has been added.

```
dotnet new -i MassTransit.Templates
```

[image]

I then run the following as stated in the video

```
dotnet new mtworker -n WorkerService
```

But its just states an error that it cant find the template

[image]

Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the video is already outdated, it just needs to be worker now!

```
dotnet new worker -n WorkerService
```

A bit general now, think I liked mtworker

This can be seen here https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the MassTransit projects, the templates are not properly installed. While you listed the install step in your question, I don't think it applied on your system correctly.

You should see the following templates when typing just `dotnet new` by itself:

```
MassTransit Routing Slip Activity                 mtactivity               [C#]              MassTransit/Activity
MassTransit Message Consumer                      mtconsumer               [C#]              MassTransit/Consumer
MassTransit Docker                                mtdocker                 [C#]              MassTransit/Docker
MassTransit Routing Slip Execute Activity         mtexecactivity           [C#]              MassTransit/ExecuteActivity
MassTransit Consumer Saga                         mtsaga                   [C#]              MassTransit/Saga
MassTransit State Machine Saga                    mtstatemachine           [C#]              MassTransit/StateMachine
MassTransit Worker                                mtworker                 [C#]              MassTransit/Worker
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks, I've updated the output from the "dotnet new -i MassTransit.Templates" command with a screenshot ^. So are you saying the mtworker should also work? I seem to be able to use it now with just "new worker" and following the textual guide. 
Looks like the templates did not install but no errors...hmmm.

Comment: Doesn't look like they're added to your setup. I'd troubleshoot the install issue, I have no idea why they aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, make sure nuget.org is set.

[image]

You can also set this by editing the user scope configuration file located at %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config (Windows) and ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config (Mac/Linux).

[image]